# Remove in between folder structure from the url in a php website

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wampserver

I have a php website having following folder structure (basic structure).

- project_name

  - app

    - controller
    - model
    - view
  - css
  - js
  - img
  - index.php

So when I view index.php in WAMP the url is `http://localhost/project_name/`

But when I go inside the site (eg. login.php which resides under view folder) url is like this. `http://localhost/project_name/app/view/login.php`

I found that using .htaccess we can change the urls. So I tried this (in .htaccess).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /project_name/app/view/login.php /project_name/login.php
RewriteRule ^/project_name/login.php$ /project_name/app/view/login.php [L]
```

Now url is `http://localhost/project_name/login.php` It is correct. But it seems php does not use the original link to grab the file (ie. from `/project_name/app/view/login.php`) but from here `/project_name/login.php`

So it throws 404 error.

What should I change? Please help me, i am just trying to hide `/app/view/` part from the url so that user won't see my folder structure. I have read about various ways of doing that for about 9hrs today but still couldn't get anything working correctly.

Hope my question is clear enough. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't be linking directly to views anyway .. you would either link to controllers or have a router that gets the controller to use based on the request

Comment: I use controllers to access models and to create dynamic pages based on the data retieved from the models. Functions in controllers are the ones that complete final view page. Can you explain how to do it in the way you said and does it hide the /app/view/ part from my url?

Comment: normally the entire `app` folder would be out of the document root entirely and you would do everything through `index.php`, which would inspect the route and include the files it needs to display/process.

Comment: ok.. thnx. I'll try that. But isn't it going to slow the site? And apart from that how do you use .htaccess to change url the user sees?

Comment: May slow the site a little, but I doubt you'd notice.  You wouldn't have to use `.htaccess`, just route everything to `index.php` and it will take care of you.

Comment: Take a deeper look into some frameworks supporting this (all probably?), eg. Nette and it's router :)

Comment: I am a newbie to these things. But I have worked with frameworks which does this url modificating things just like @Seth said. So i want to learn how to do it in my own small framework/site. Does anybody know a good reference to learn these things? Of course I have done a lot of google searching and read many posts about .htaccess but still couldn't grasp it.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I took your advice and changed my application. I think now my problems are solved. So the problem has been I have misunderstood mvc architecture + php. I always thought with Grails in mind. With having index.php as a router my problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: @pabz You're welcome; too bad I didn't write an answer, huh

Comment: @ExplosionPills yeah then i could have marked it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

URI's passed through rewrite rules in an htaccess file has the leading slash removed, so your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/project_name/login.php$ /project_name/app/view/login.php [L]
```

won't ever match anything because of `^/`. Also, since you are rewriting to a URI that matches a previous redirect, your browser will see a redirect loop and say that it's not redirecting properly. You'll need to match against the actual request and not the URI:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /project_name/app/view/login\.php
RewriteRule ^ /project_name/login.php [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?project_name/login.php$ /project_name/app/view/login.php [L]
```

Comment: Above .htaccess code did not hide `/app/view/` but creates a redirect loop and browser says that it's not redirecting properly. So it didn't work. But my earlier code didn't do anything like that. It just gave 404 Not Found error because now the url is changed. So I think there is some error in this given .htaccess. I am a newbie to these things. But I have worked with frameworks which does this url modificating things just like @Seth said. So i want to learn how to do it in my own small framework/site. Does anybody know a good reference to learn these things?

Comment: @pabz Sorry, there was a copy paste error with the first rule that matches against `%{THE_REQUEST}`.

Comment: Thnx @Jon Lin But now it gives 404 error. Why does it say `The requested URL /project_name/login.php was not found on this server.` Do i need to create a symbolic link in /project_name/login.php (to link to /project_name/app/view/login.php) ?